Different Notions of Degree Agree
Vakil's (late February 2024 edition) notes define the degree of a line bundle $\mathscr{L}$ on projective curve $C$ over field $k$ to be $\chi(C, \mathscr{L}) - \chi(C, \mathscr{O}_C)$. On the other hand, the degree of a projective $k$-scheme $X$ of dimension $n$ is defined as $n!$ times the leading coefficient of the Hilbert polynomial of $X$, so $n! \cdot h^0(C, \mathscr{O}_C(1))$.
I am trying to show that if regular curve $C$ has degree $d$ line bundle $\mathscr{L}$ inducing closed embedding into projective space, then the degree of $C$ in this embedding is $d$ as well. It's suggested to use Riemann-Roch in some form, but it doesn't seem like there is enough information, even if I do take the divisor associate to some section of $\mathscr{L}$. If this is a hypersurface, I can use the closed subscheme exact sequence, but that isn't necessarily the case. I have been trying to do this all day and am frustrated since I get the feeling that the solution is very obvious.
Any hints or tips would be welcome!

Generally, if $X$ is a projective $k$-scheme and $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ is a very ample line bundle, the Hilbert polynomial of $X$ associated to this line bundle is given (for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$) by $m \mapsto \chi(X, \mathcal{O}_X(m))$. Note that it's not immediately obvious that this function is a polynomial, but this can be checked fairly easily by induction on dimension.
We will show the Hilbert polynomial defined above agrees with the classical Hilbert polynomial for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ sufficiently large, to conclude they are equal. If $I \subset k[x_0, \dots, x_n]$ is a homogeneous ideal, it defines a projective subscheme $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ by taking the associated coherent ideal sheaf $\tilde{I}$. Then we can view $$\overline{I}:=\bigoplus H^0(\mathbb{P}^n, \tilde{I}(n)) = \{f \in k[x_0, \dots, x_n]\;|\;\text{for each }i = 0, \dots, n\text{ there is some } r \text{ so that }x_i^r f \in I\} \subset k[x_0, \dots, x_n]$$
The homogeneous ideal $\overline{I}$ is usually called the saturation of $I$, and naturally contains $I$. From the above equality one can readily show that $\overline{I}_d = I_d$ for $d$ sufficiently large, by looking at generators. As such, although they may differ, their associated coherent ideal sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^n$ are the same. Using Serre vanishing, this also implies that $I_d = H^0(\mathbb{P}^n, \tilde{I}(d)) = \chi(\mathbb{P}^n, \tilde{I}(d))$ for $d$ sufficiently large. That way, using the exact sequence $$0 \longrightarrow  \tilde{I}(m) \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(m) \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X}(m)\longrightarrow 0$$ we compute the Hilbert polynomial of $X$ to be $$m \mapsto \dim_k(k[x_0, \dots x_n]_m) - \dim_k(\overline{I}_m)= \dim_k(k[x_0, \dots x_n]_m) - \dim_k(I_m)$$ where this is all for $m$ sufficiently large. But then, the quantity on the right side of the above equality agrees with the classical Hilbert polynomial of $X$.
In our case we're taking $X = C$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(1) = \mathscr{L}$, so that the Hilbert polynomial is explicitly given by $m \mapsto \chi(C, \mathscr{L}^m)$. Since degree is additive, Riemann-Roch then tells us that the Hilbert polynomial of $C$ is given by $$\chi(C, \mathscr{L}^m) = m\deg(\mathscr{L}) - g + 1.$$ This is predictably a linear polynomial in $m$ and evidently, the coefficient of $m$ is just the degree of $\mathscr{L}$.

Thanks for the excellent answer! I blanked and forgot that pulling back the structure sheaf of P^n is exactly that of C since there is an inclusion. I appreciate your connecting this to the classical Hilbert polynomial as well.
